# React state for array is not appended using spread operator

Tags: javascript, reactjs, loops, return, state

I'm creating Sudoku app using React.js.

I've faced an issue of values being written to state `sudoku` only after first inner loop of `createSudokValues()` (which creates only the first row of sudoku). The outer loop is supposed to generate the rest of the rows (by `setSudoku(prevSquares => [ ...prevSquares, ...row]);`).

What am I missing? Thanks!

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import '../App.css';
import { SquareType } from '../interfaces/customInterfaces';
import Square from './Square';

function App() {
    let row: Array<SquareType> = [];
    const [sudoku, setSudoku] = useState<SquareType[]>([]);
    const possibleOptionsForDigit = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

    function generateRandomArrayIndex(unusedDigits: Array<number> ) {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * unusedDigits.length);
    }

    function unusedDigitInRowAndColumn( sudoku: Array<SquareType>, row: Array<SquareType>, columnIndex: number ) {
        let digitsExistingInRow: Array<number> = [];
        let digitsExistingInColumn: Array<number> = [];
        let unusedDigitsInRow: Array<number> = [];
        let unusedDigitsInColumn: Array<number> = [];
        let unusedDigits: Array<number>;
        let randomDigitFromUnused: number;
        
        digitsExistingInRow = row.map(square => square.digit);
        unusedDigitsInRow = possibleOptionsForDigit.filter(digit => !digitsExistingInRow.includes(digit));
    
        digitsExistingInColumn = sudoku.filter(square => square.index === columnIndex).map(square => square.digit);
        unusedDigitsInColumn = possibleOptionsForDigit.filter(digit => !digitsExistingInColumn.includes(digit));
    
        unusedDigits = unusedDigitsInRow.filter(digit => unusedDigitsInColumn.includes(digit)); 
        randomDigitFromUnused = unusedDigits[generateRandomArrayIndex(unusedDigits)];
    
        return randomDigitFromUnused;
    }

    function createSudokValues() {
        let generatedUnusedDigit: number = 0;

        for ( let y = 1; y <= 9; y++ ) {
            for ( let columnIndex = 1; columnIndex <= 9; columnIndex++ ) {
                while (row.length <= 9) {
                    console.log('row ', row)
                    generatedUnusedDigit = unusedDigitInRowAndColumn(sudoku, row, columnIndex);
                    row.push(
                        {
                            digit: generatedUnusedDigit,
                            index: columnIndex,
                            shown: true
                        }
                    );
                    break;
                }
                
            }
            // end of inner loop

            // eslint-disable-next-line no-loop-func
            setSudoku(prevSquares => [ ...prevSquares, ...row]);
            row = [];
            // end of outer loop
        }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('sudoku ', sudoku)
    });

    useEffect(() => {
        createSudokValues();
        // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
    }, []);

    return (
        <div className="App">
            <div className="pageContainer">
                <p>
                    Sudoku
                </p>
                <div className="sudokuContainer">
                    {
                        sudoku.map((square, idx) =>
                        <Square key={idx} {...square}></Square>
                        )
                    }
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

This is the first row printed to the screen:

[image: sudoku]

Which is equivalent to the first row console.logged:

[image: First row in sudoku]

[image: console.logged sudoku]

Comment: rather than calling `setSudoku` within the loop, which is triggering a render on each call, accumulate the rows and call `setSudoko` once outside of the loop with the full matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of using a variable inside the function you should initialize the row array every time the first loop runs.

So this function:

```
function createSudokValues() {
    let generatedUnusedDigit: number = 0;

    for ( let y = 1; y <= 9; y++ ) {
        for ( let columnIndex = 1; columnIndex <= 9; columnIndex++ ) {
            while (row.length <= 9) {
                console.log('row ', row)
                generatedUnusedDigit = unusedDigitInRowAndColumn(sudoku, row, columnIndex);
                row.push(
                    {
                        digit: generatedUnusedDigit,
                        index: columnIndex,
                        shown: true
                    }
                );
                break;
            }
            
        }
        // end of inner loop

        // eslint-disable-next-line no-loop-func
        setSudoku(prevSquares => [ ...prevSquares, ...row]);
        row = [];
        // end of outer loop
    }
}
```

should be:

```
function createSudokValues() {
    let generatedUnusedDigit = 0;

    let row: Array<SquareType> = [];
    let tempSudoku: Array<SquareType> = [];
    for (let y = 1; y <= 9; y++) {
      for (let columnIndex = 1; columnIndex <= 9; columnIndex++) {
        while (row.length <= 9) {
          console.log("row ", row);
          generatedUnusedDigit = unusedDigitInRowAndColumn(
            sudoku,
            row,
            columnIndex
          );
          row.push({
            digit: generatedUnusedDigit,
            index: columnIndex,
            shown: true
          });
          break;
        }
        tempSudoku.push(...row);
        row = [];
      }
    }
    setSudoku(tempSudoku);
  }
```

It makes little sense to setState inside the loop because it would be bad for performance reasons, since state variable would trigger useless renders.
And also you should remove the `let row: Array<SquareType> = [];` initialization at the beginning of the App component.

Comment: I've amended the code as per your suggestion except I've declared `let row: Array<SquareType>; before line `for ( let y = 1; y <= 9; y++ ) {}` so that this variable would be accessible outside of the inner loop and have assigned a value `row = [];` at the first line of `for ( let y = 1; y <= 9; y++ ) {}` loop. However, this hasn't solved the problem

Comment: So you need the last row after the loop? If that's the case i've updated my answer, but it makes little sense since you can access it though the board, also you don't need to setState inside the loop because it would be bad for performance reasons, since state variables trigger useless renders

Comment: The last row however will always be cleared so just access the last row like so:   sudoku[i][j] = sudoku[ i * 9 + j ]  -->  sudoku[8][j] = sudoku[ 8 * 9 + j ]

Comment: Many thanks, that's what I wanted to achieve - to generate 9 rows of 9 squares in each. However, after using your amended code and adding `console.log("ROW BEFORE PASSING", row)` after line `while (row.length <= 9) {` I can see that the values of row there are always `= []` and therefore `row = []` values are passed to `unusedDigitInRowAndColumn()` every time which is not correct